# How to add page selection field to wordpress theme customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create several sections in the customization section of the WordPress theme, each section connected to a page of the template (for example: `home page, single page, single product page, 404 page`).

I searched a lot to get this code, but I could only find the following code, which links to the template pages instead of linking to the main pages of the template:

```
function prefix_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'showcase' , array(
            'title'      => __( 'Showcase', 'textdomain' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );

    for ( $count = 1; $count <= 1; $count++ ) {

        // Add color scheme setting and control.
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'showcase-page-' . $count, array(
            'default'           => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'showcase-page-' . $count, array(
            'label'    => __( 'Select Page', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'showcase',
            'type'     => 'dropdown-pages'
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'prefix_customize_register' );
```

**Is what I'm looking for workable or not?**

I need any kind of help or guidance on this.

---

Edit:

I'm mostly looking for a code to introduce it to WordPress customization by placing a command on the desired page (for example: `Single`) and then add color, text and image fields to it.

Comment: Can you please clarify your distinction between “template pages” versus “main pages of the template”?

Comment: Hello. I mean the main pages: `404 `- `single` - `home`. And I mean the non-main pages of the tab: `shop` - `payment` - `shopping` cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll likely want to explicitly define the sections for each template, and then add the fields per template. You could probably automate detection of templates, but that’s better as a future improvement rather than something to bother with now.

Try this article for in-depth explanation of panes, sections, and fields: https://www.usablewp.com/learn-wordpress/wordpress-customizer/how-to-add-a-panel-section-and-controls-to-the-customize-panel/.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I got all the codes for professional customization and made the changes I wanted. Now I just want to categorize the fields of each page in a separate field so that the customization part of WordPress will be more organized.

Comment: For example: I created the `color`, `text` and `image` fields for the `single` page and now I want the user to click on the single page field to be redirected to it through customization and apply the desired changes.

Comment: In addition, I am very grateful for your very good guidance that made me progress well in this area.

Comment: You’ll use the `add_section()` method like you did for “Showcase”.

Comment: Please, if it is possible, write me a piece of code so that I can define the single page in a separate field or introduce me to a brief tutorial about this part.

Comment: Added link to article.

Comment: Thank you. This was the best and most concise tutorial. Again, thank you very much for your time.